# Unable to move asio::ssl::stream to handler

Tags: c++, asio

Asio v1.20 standalone library [server example](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/src/examples/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp) shows how `asio::ssl::stream` is moved from the server class to the session class. When I try to compile the example, it throws me an error:

```
/home/user/tmp/tmp.ZxZvgK7sGZ/main.cpp: In constructor ‘session::session(asio::ssl::stream<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp> >)’:
/home/user/tmp/tmp.ZxZvgK7sGZ/main.cpp:23:34: error: use of deleted function ‘asio::ssl::stream<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp> >::stream(const asio::ssl::stream<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp> >&)’
   23 |       : socket_(std::move(socket))
      |                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/asio/ssl.hpp:22,
                 from /home/user/tmp/tmp.ZxZvgK7sGZ/main.cpp:15:
/usr/include/asio/ssl/stream.hpp:63:7: note: ‘asio::ssl::stream<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp> >::stream(const asio::ssl::stream<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp> >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   63 | class stream :
      |       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/asio/ssl/stream.hpp:63:7: error: ‘asio::detail::noncopyable::noncopyable(const asio::detail::noncopyable&)’ is private within this context
```

I understand that I can't move my `asio::ssl::stream` because it is noncopyable, or am I missing something? How to make the example above compile?

I tried to use [Asio standalone library](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/doc/) with ASIO_HAS_MOVE as well.

Compiler:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

**PROBLEM & SOLUTION**

I installed the Asio library as a [Debian package](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libasio-dev) `libasio-dev` for which I didn't check the version. It is [v1.18](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libasio-dev). I installed it from source now and it works, as @dewaffled pointed out.

Comment: [should be](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/f70f65ae54351c209c3a24704624144bfe8e70a3/asio/include/asio/ssl/stream.hpp#L120) movable. you should probably check `/usr/include/asio/ssl/stream.hpp` you have, maybe it is just outdated library version.

Comment: I see where I did my mistake. I installed Asio library as an [Ubuntu package](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libasio-dev) `libasio-dev` for which I didn't check the version. It is [v1.18](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libasio-dev). I installed it from the source now and it works.